# Linking to a specific tab from another page html

Tags: javascript, html

i have two html. 
the first html, I have this: (only links)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>index</title>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
<a href="tabs.html#tab3" >link tab3</a>
<br>
<a href="tabs.html#tab5">link tab5</a>          
</body>
</html>
```

- and the second html, I have the taps.

  tabs
      
      
              
                      tab1
                      tab2
                       tab3
                      tab4
                       tab5
                       tab6

  #### tab1

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, fugit, et ab omnis obcaecati temporibus beatae nobis nostrum odit accusantium numquam ex deleniti animi voluptates officiis explicabo ipsa iusto eius!

  ```
     <div id="tab2" class="tab-grid2">    
      <h3>tab2</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, fugit, et ab omnis obcaecati temporibus beatae nobis nostrum odit accusantium numquam ex deleniti animi voluptates officiis explicabo ipsa iusto eius!</p> 
            </div> <!-- /.tab2 --> 

             <div id="tab3" class="tab-grid3">    
             <h3>tab3</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, fugit, et ab omnis obcaecati temporibus beatae nobis nostrum odit accusantium numquam ex deleniti animi voluptates officiis explicabo ipsa iusto eius!</p> 
           </div> <!-- /.tab3 -->        

             <div id="tab4" class="tab-grid4">
             <h3>tab4</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, fugit, et ab omnis obcaecati temporibus beatae nobis nostrum odit accusantium numquam ex deleniti animi voluptates officiis explicabo ipsa iusto eius!</p> 
           </div> <!-- /.tab4 -->     

             <div id="tab5" class="tab-grid5">    
                <h3>tab5</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, fugit, et ab omnis obcaecati temporibus beatae nobis nostrum odit accusantium numquam ex deleniti animi voluptates officiis explicabo ipsa iusto eius!</p>
           </div> <!-- /.tab5 --> 

           <div id="tab6" class="tab-grid6">
           <h3>tab6</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, fugit, et ab omnis obcaecati temporibus beatae nobis nostrum odit accusantium numquam ex deleniti animi voluptates officiis explicabo ipsa iusto eius!</p>
           </div> <!-- /.tab7 --> 

      <!-- jQuery-->  
       <script src="jquery.js"></script>

          <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#tab2").hide();
              $("#tab3").hide();
              $("#tab4").hide();
              $("#tab5").hide();
              $("#tab6").hide();
              $("#tab7").hide();
              $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  var tab=$(this).attr("href");
                  $(".tab-grid1,.tab-grid2,.tab-grid3,.tab-grid4,.tab-grid5,.tab-grid6,.tab-grid7").not(tab).css("display","none");
                  $(tab).fadeIn("slow");
              });
              $("ul.tabs-menu li a").click(function(){
                  $(this).parent().addClass("active a");
                  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active a");
              });
          });
          </script>
  </body>
  ```

**How can I do to send me to a specific tab, for example tab # 3, becouse always send me to tab # 1**

Comment: you need to check `document.location.hash` to see which tab is to be displayed

Comment: Search Search Search..